# How reset all Interactive grid Filters Oracle APEX as Page Load Procedure from another page

Tags: javascript, apex, apex-code

I have an Interactive Grid on "page 6" that I would like to reset from "page 7" with a Page Load Dynamic Action.

I have set the Static ID of the Interactive Grid to IR.

When I add this code to the page with the Interactive Grid "page 6" , it works fine and clears the filter.

```
apex.region("IR").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("reset-report");
```

But when I try to add this in "page 4",  I get the following error.

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'widget') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'widget')
```

Comment: what is the flow ? Are you navigating from page 7 to page 6 with a branch/link ?